# How to reduce throughput in Talend?

Tags: talend

I am trying to reduce the throughput to 3 rows/s. I tried searching for this online but didn't find much. Can anybody help?

My current job looks like this:

[image: Job layout]

Or is it possible to limit tHTTPRequests in the component?

Comment: Why not just `LIMIT` your Postgres query?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR But that would only process a limited number of rows. I need to reduce the number of processed rows each second. See the pic

Comment: Ah, apologies, I misread your question to just wanting 3 rows rather than 3 rows/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will want to use the [tSleep component](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tSleep) that will introduce a wait time per row.

The wait time is in seconds but you might be able to use a floating point value (eg. `0.3333`). Otherwise you'll be limited to 1 row/s.

If you can't use a floating point value in the tSleep configuration and you absolutely need 3 rows per second then you could use a tJavaRow component that passes everything in the input to the output but also uses this snippet of Java code:

```
Thread.sleep(333);
```

This will sleep the running thread for 333 milliseconds on each row of data being passed through the component and give you roughly 3 rows per second (minus actual processing time which in this case should be minimal).

Comment: Perfect. The java row worked perfectly. The tSleep component would've worked too but double values can't be entered and I am too paranoid to modify the code. The tJavaRow component is a goldmine. I think the other question I posted could use this component also I quess.

Comment: The tJava* components can be very powerful but should be used sparingly as they undermine the entire idea of using a tool like Talend for your ETL process if you are just going to put all your logic in there. For little things like this they're fine and for when things simply cannot be done with the existing components then use them but otherwise try and stick to the components.